# Get all word forms used in mysql full text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, stemming

I am using full text search feature of mysql for searching through comments. To use stemming, I am using "form of" in the query. This gives me the correct result, returning all comments having the any word form of the search text.

However, I need to highlight all these word forms in the comments displayed, and as a result I need the entire list of word forms. How do I get the list of these word forms.

Currently, my query looks like :-

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (comment_text)
AGAINST (' FORM OF "search_term"' );
```

I require a list of all the word forms of the search_term, which were used by mysql internally.

Comment: `FORM OF` is not a native MySQL modifier. The only native way to search for word stems is with the `*` wildcard operator `IN BOOLEAN MODE`. You must be using a third party plugin?

Comment: No, I'm not using any third party plugins.

Comment: It looks like the FORM OF syntax is planned for release 7.1.  http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2423